# What is the maximum run length in PCIe gen 3 serial stream?

Tags: pcie

PCIe gen 2 uses 8b/10b and the run length is 5.  What is it for Gen 3?
Thank you for help.

Comment: 128/130b encoding. Don't know what the run length is.

Comment: Yes! Thx.  But what is the worst case run length?  I suspect some sort of scrambling is also done on the data.

Comment: Scrambling is done, yes, using the polynomial \$G(X) = X^{23} + X^{21} + X^{16} + X^8 + X^5 + X^2 + 1\$. If you can find a copy of the PCIe Base Spec Rev 3.0, the scrambler is described on page 213 onwards.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64b/66b_encoding) might also be useful reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PCIe gen 3 uses 128b/130b line coding, so absolute worst case run length would be 129 bits (128 scrambled bits + half of the 2 bit sync header). This assumes that the scrambling PRBS and transmit data exactly coincide and cancel to zeros for the entire 128 bit data block, which is possible but extremely unlikely.  Note that in contrast with 64b/66b, the 128b/130b line code does not use a self-synchronizing scrambler.  The DC wander is statistically bounded (as opposed to absolutely bounded) due to the scrambling.